# Can please anyone helps me to revise these Line

Tags: grammar, word-choice

I am a man who not speaks gut English..., I have a Website with two Language, Spanish and English because my English is very bad, First employ google Translate, then Grammarly and later with my bad English remediate it...now have a little problem with these Line...

> In July 2019 Debian release a new stable version, his name is Debian 10 Buster, it will receive support over the next five years. I will explain here with this Tutorial how to Install Debian 10 Buster with Mate and Nvidia, but it is working similarly with all Desktop's (Gnome, Kde, Lxde, Lxqt, Xfce, Cinnamon, Debian and Mate).

Can Please anyone helps me to remediate these line...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a Linux expert, but here's my attempt at rewriting the sentence.

> In July 2019, Debian released a new stable version named Debian 10
>   Buster. Debian says it will provide support for Buster for the next
>   five years. In this tutorial, I explain how to install Debian 10
>   Buster with Mate and Nvidia, but my instructions work similarly across
>   all desktops (Gnome, Kde, Lxde, Lxqt, Xfce, Cinnamon, Debian and
>   Mate).

Comment: very Thanks! , a more question ... what do you think about my English grammatical writing, where are my weaknesses?

Comment: It's hard for me to say. I suggest checking out the English Learners Stack Exchange for better guidance: https://ell.stackexchange.com/